# How to move the caption to the top of the rotated table

Tags: tables, captions

Is it possible to move the caption to the top of the table?

Thanks for any help

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[figuresleft]{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\newcommand*\OK{\checkmark}
\begin{document}
\clearpage
\begin{sidewaystable}[!t]
\caption{SQL injection mitigation techniques FCA}
\label{tbl:fcaSQL}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline

\shortstack[]{CANDID} & \rot{\OK} & {} & \rot{\OK} & {} & {} & {} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & {} & {} & {} & 
\rot{\OK} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} \\ \cline{1-19}

\shortstack[]{CSSE} & \rot{\OK} & {} & {} & {} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & {} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} &
\rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & {} & {} & {} & \rot{\OK} & {} \\ \cline{1-19}

\shortstack[1]{SQLCheck} & \rot{\OK} & {} & {} & {} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & {} & {} & {} & {} &
\rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & {} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} \\ \cline{1-19}

\shortstack[]{SQLGuard} & {} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & {} & {} & { } & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & { } & {} & {} &
\rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & { } & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} \\ \cline{1-19}

\shortstack[]{SQLProb} & {} & \rot{\OK} & { } & {} & \rot{\OK} & { } & \rot{\OK} & {} & { } & {} & {} &
\rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} \\ \cline{1-19}

\shortstack[]{SQLrand} & {} & \rot{\OK} & {} & \rot{\OK} & {} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & {} & {} & {} &
\rot{\OK} & {} & \rot{\OK} & {} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & {} \\ \cline{1-19}

\shortstack[]{WASP} & \rot{\OK} & {} & { } & {} & \rot{\OK} & { } & {} & {} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & {} &
\rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & { } & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} \\ \cline{1-19}

\shortstack[]{Header\\Sanitization} & {} & \rot{\OK} & {} & \rot{\OK} & {} & {} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & {} & \rot{\OK} &
\rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} \\ \cline{1-19}

\shortstack[]{Network\\Analyzer} & \rot{\OK} & {} & {} & {} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & {} & {} & \rot{\OK} & {} & \rot{\OK} &
\rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & {} & {} & {} & {} \\ \cline{1-19}

\shortstack[]{Web App\\Firewall} & {} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & {} & {} & {} & {} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & {} & \rot{\OK} &
\rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & \rot{\OK} & {} & {} & {} & {} \\ \cline{1-19}

\rot{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{Mitigation}\\ \textbf{Name}}} &
\rot{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{Low}\\ \textbf{Programmer}\\ \textbf{Involvement}}} &
\rot{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{High}\\ \textbf{Programmer}\\ \textbf{Involvement}}} &
\rot{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{Automatic Code}\\ \textbf{Modification}}} &
\rot{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{Manual Code}\\ \textbf{Modification}}} &
\rot{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{No Code}\\ \textbf{Modification}}} &
\rot{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{Additional}\\ \textbf{Infrastructure}}} &
\rot{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{Open Source}}} &
\rot{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{Lang. Specific}}} &
\rot{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{Active}\\ \textbf{Development}}} &
\rot{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{Tracking}}} &
\rot{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{GET/POST}}} &
\rot{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{Tautology * }}} &
\rot{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{Logically }\\ \textbf{Incorrect * }}} &
\rot{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{Union Query * }}} &
\rot{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{Stored}\\ \textbf{Procedures * }}} &
\rot{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{Piggy-Back}\\ \textbf{Query * }}} &
\rot{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{Inference * }}} &
\rot{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{Alternative}\\ \textbf{Encodings * }}}\\ \cline{1-19}


\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `table` float and rotate -90 degrees the tabular environment solve *that* problem ...

```
\begin{table}[!t]
\caption{SQL injection mitigation techniques FCA}
\label{tbl:fcaSQL}
\centering
\rotatebox{-90}{\begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

But note the bottom margin and how it look ...

> [image: mwe]

What I would do could be more like this ...

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabulary}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox[origin=tr]{-90}}
\newcommand*\OK{\checkmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\belowcaptionskip1ex
\caption{SQL injection mitigation techniques FCA}
\label{tbl:fcaSQL}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{>{\em}lCCCCCCCCCC}\toprule
Mitigation Name         & 
\rot{CANDID} & 
\rot{CSSE} & 
\rot{SQLCheck} & 
\rot{SQLGuard} & 
\rot{SQLProb} & 
\rot{SQLrand} & 
\rot{WASP} & 
\rot{Header Sanitization} & 
\rot{Network Analyzer} & 
\rot{Web App Firewall} \\\midrule
Low  Programmer Involvement & \OK &  &  &  & \OK &  & \OK &  \\
High Programmer Involvement &  & \OK & \OK & \OK &  & \OK &  & \OK \\
Automatic Code Modification &  &  & \OK &  &  &  &  &  & \OK \\
Manual Code Modification    &  &  &  &  & \OK &  & \OK &  &  \\
No Code Modification        & \OK & \OK &  & \OK &  & \OK &  & \OK &  \\
Additional Infrastructure   & \OK & \OK &  &  & \OK &  &  & \OK &  \\
Open Source                 & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK &  & \OK &  &  \\
Language Specific           & \OK & \OK &  & \OK &  & \OK &  & \OK &  & \OK \\
Active Development          &  &  &  &  &  & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK \\
Tracking                    &  & \OK &  &  &  &  & \OK &  &  &  \\
GET/POST                    &  & \OK &  &  &  &  &  & \OK & \OK & \OK \\
Tautology *                 & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK \\
Logically Incorrect *       & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK &  & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK \\
Union Query *               &  &  & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK &  & \OK & \OK \\
Stored Procedures *         &  &  &  & \OK &  &  &  &  &  \\
Piggy-Back Query *          &  & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK &  &  &  \\
Inference *                 &  & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK & \OK &  &  &  \\
Alternative Encodings *     &  & \OK & \OK & \OK &  & \OK &  &  & \\\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```